# Transforming folder values into dataframe column when reading partitioned data

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

I'm trying to read multiple parquet files from multiple folders, and I want the folders to be a column on my dataframe.

Example:

Folders

```
anomesdia=20230426
anomesdia=20230425
anomesdia=20230424
```

When I read this folder, I got a dataframe with these columns:

```
id | customer | card 
1     6          8
```

And I need this, with the folder value as one column:

```
id | customer | card  |  anomesdia
1     6          8        20230426
```

Could I get this? I have no idea on how to do and I am not finding solutions on google

Answer (score 0):

Put your files in this folder structure

```
/home/glue_user/workspace
├── anomesdia=20230424
│   └── data.csv
├── anomesdia=20230425
│   └── data.csv
└── anomesdia=20230426
    └── data.csv
```

Then read using

```
path='/home/glue_user/workspace'
df = spark.read.option('header', True).csv(path)
```

Reference: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#partition-discovery